# alternate for multiple constructors

Tags: python, architecture

I have a class that has a constructor like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options
    .....
```

At times I initiate an instance of this class by passing `options`, for example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='something')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--victor', dest='vic')
options = parser.parse_args()
x = MyClass(options)
```

This works fine, however, there are some scenarios when there will be no options passed, so for those scenarios I've created a method in `MyClass` that will create default option like this.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options

    def create_default_parser(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='something')
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--victor', dest='vic', default="winning")
        options = parser.parse_args()
        self.options = options
```

**Question**

How should I initiate an instance of this class when I don't want to pass any `options` and use the `create_default_parser`?
Ideally I would make another constructor that doesn't accept any parameters and in that constructor I would call `create_default_parser`, like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.create_default_parser()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do something like this. One way would be to have the options have a default value that indicates that you want the default. This could look like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        if options is None:
            options = create_default_parser()
        self.options = options

    def create_default_parser(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='something')
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--victor', dest='vic', default="winning")
        options = parser.parse_args()
        return options
```

initializing the default would then look like

```
default = MyClass()
```

Another method would be to use a class method like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options

    @classmethod
    def create_default_parser(cls):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='something')
        parser.add_argument('-v', '--victor', dest='vic', default="winning")
        options = parser.parse_args()
        return cls(options)
```

and the default would be created like this:

```
default = MyClass.create_default_parser()
```

Comment: The default would be created without passing an argument.

Comment: What zondo said. Otherwise using a `classmethod` as a factory is a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a keyword argument with a default value.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        if options is not None:
            self.options = options
        else:
            self.create_default_parser()
```

This can then be called with either

```
MyClass(options)
```

or

```
MyClass()  # calls create_default_parser()
```